# DateFormat of non standard calendar

Tags: java, android, date-format

I'm trying to use user's date format configurations to format my date, but the calendar I use is not the normal Gregorian calendar and so the number of days and year is completely different. as such I can't just pass milliseconds to DateFormat.

I can already get the Year, Month and Day in my own calendar and format each number but then I have to hard code the date style. here's the code i use now:

```
java.text.DateFormat timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(MyApplication.getSharedApplication());
Locale currentLocal = MyApplication.getSharedApplication().getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
JalaliCalendar calendar = new JalaliCalendar(new Date(unixTime));
return calendar.getJalalidate(currentLocal)+"  "+timeFormat.format(unixTime);


public String getJalalidate(Locale loc) {
    return String.format(loc, "%02d",year) + "/" + String.format(loc, "%02d",month) + "/" + String.format(loc, "%02d", date);
}
```

so here's my question. how can i fine tune this further so that YYYY/MM/DD is not hard-coded?

many thanks

Comment: "as such I can't just pass milliseconds to DateFormat" - why not? It's still the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, regardless of calendar... `java.util.Date` is calendar-agnostic. Can you not use `SimpleDateFormat` (having specified the calendar) and pass in the relevant pattern? I'm not quite sure what the problem is here...

Comment: dateFormat.format(milis) will give gregorian date regardless of user locale. also i don't want to use simpleDateFormat since i want to use the user's chosen style.

Comment: Not if you specify the calendar system for `dateFormat` using `DateFormat.setCalendar`.

Comment: I did try that with a class that extended Calendar and implemented my own. but it didn't work in the end. I don't think I have the correct knowledge to implement a full calendar system and most ready code deals with date conversion rather than full implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you want then. The way to use a different calendar with `DateFormat` is to use `DateFormat.setCalendar`. If you're not going to implement a full `Calendar`, you're not going to be able to use that approach...

Comment: I was searching for the way to pass to Year,Month and Day values directly and expected a formatted string. or get the format the user has chosen and format my pure year/month/date values based on that.